# Swift - Realm migration to copy a property to its children

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Hi I’m stuck with my project with RealmSwift as I need to perform a migration.

I have 2 models. Let’s make them simple and so call them `Parent` and `Child`

Here is the simple representation of the realm objects.

```
class Parent: Object {
   @Persisted var id: Int
   @Persisted var name: String
   @Persisted var children: [Child]
}

class Child: Object {
   @Persisted var name: String
}
```

Now I’d like to let the `Child` to have a property called `parentId` and copy the Parent’s id to it.

How is that possible with realm migration?

thanks for in advance ! :)

I have tried to implement iterating the children on Parent object. But I’m not sure how to and if that even works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A couple of things. First, those are not Realm objects so no migration is possible. Second thing, you may not want to "copy the parents id" (a string) to other objects - there's often no reason to. You can simple refer the the actual parent object instead of it's id string. `@Persisted var myParent: Parent` for example. Actually, you can do one better by adding a `LinkingObjects` property to the Child which automagically creates a back-link the the parent so then you can transverse the graph in both directions. Can you clarify the question with your actual code and models?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the code in the original post was not the actual code of realm object. I have updated the post. Thanks for suggesting the LinkingObjects. 
What I am trying here is to set the `parentId` on `Child` and search by `parentId` like `realm.objects(Child.self).filter(...)`. And hopefully this can be achieved by realm's migration function.
I know the data model has been poorly designed initially, but I need this now 

Comment: I hate to be picky, but this `@Persisted var children: [Child]` will not work. If the intent is to have a list of child objects, you would need to leverage the [List](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/object-models/#about-these-examples) property type `@Persisted var children = RealmSwift.List<Child>()`.

Comment: What you're attempting to do *may* be a bad idea; it ties each child to one and only one parent, meaning the Child object is not re-usable (e.g. what if the child has two parents?). If you only want a child to tie to a single parent, then make the child an EmbeddedObject of the Parent. If you want to persist the child objects separately, then yes, you can do that in a migration block without iterating over the child objects in the List `someParent.children.setValue(someParent.id, forKey: "parent_id")` will set the parent_id on all the children in the list. (adapt for use in a migration block)

Comment: Ahhh sorry I forgot to add List<> in the example code my bad. In my project, it is correct to have only one parent for a child, as in Parent-Child is a One-to-Many relationship.
The reason I wanted to have `parentId` in the `Child` object is to make the search more efficient. Let's say a `Child` object also has a persisted property `gender`. and now if I want to search all `Child` objects whose `parentId` is greater than 200 and also the `gender` is `male`, I'd like to do perform `realm.objects(Child.self).where { $0.parentId > 200 && $0.gender == "male" }`. Thought this is more efficient ?

Comment: `EmbeddedObject` sounds like a possible solution, but the `Child` object is already declared as normal Object so that's going to raise another question. In my project the `Child` has always exactly 1 `Parent` so I assume it's possible though.

Comment: Ok, understood. You're on the right track. However, I would still shy away from storing parent id strings and store the actual Parent object in a property instead of a string. Other than that, adjust your migration per my above suggestion and you should be good to go. If you don't know how to do that, please make the attempt and the post your migration code.